# Multiprocessing, Django and OperationalError: SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected

Tags: python-2.7, django-models

I have multiprocessing running and at the end of each task I update the database with a status.

I do the save like this

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ShopPushQueue, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I get the following error though

```
DatabaseError: server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.

        cursor = super(SQLUpdateCompiler, self).execute_sql(result_type)
      File "/var/www/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-

packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 894, in execute_sql
    raise original_exception
OperationalError: SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected
```

I think I get that the connection is no longer available, but I don't understand why.  This works well when not using multiprocessing.

Is there something I should be doing to refresh the database connection?  Or maintain it

Thanks